# Specific difference between Malleable and Pliable?

Tags: synonyms

When would I use one over the other, assuming they're not exact synonyms?

Comment: What does your dictionary suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between them has to do with the degree to which shape is imposed upon the substance.

That which is **pliable** can be bent or flexed.

That which is **malleable** can be beaten or hammered into a concavity, like a bowl or a basin.

Not all pliable substances can be hammered thin.  A piece of plastic may be pliable but not malleable.  A piece of copper is both pliable and malleable.

Answer (score -1):

To be technical for a moment:

A material is *malleable* if it undergoes plastic deformation under compression.
This is the converse of a *ductile* material which undergoes plastic deformation under tension.

The term *pliable* is a somewhat less scientific term that is applied to a material that undergoes plastic deformation under a comparatively low compressive or tensile stress.

For clarity: *Plastic* deformation means that if you deform it, it stays deformed.  This is the opposite of *Elastic*, where the original shape returns once stress is removed.

To return to a less technical frame of mind:

A *malleable* material can be formed into a shape by beating it.  A *pliable* material can be formed into a shape fairly easily.

Comment: "Pliable", as commonly understood, does not necessarily imply that the material, once deformed, remains deformed.  It merely means that it is easily bent (without breaking or seriously degrading).